# LSTM - Who are the inputs for those hidden cells?

Tags: neural-networks, lstm, recurrent-neural-network, keras

I'm learning RNN and I'm understanding, but I have a specific question that I can not find answer:

What is the `x` input for the cells (pointed in **yellow**) for the LSTM structure *Many to Many* (when `time_steps < hidden_cells_unit`)?
Image to exemplify:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Typically, the output at time $t-1$ is fed as the input at time $t$ for this kind of model.